# How do I confirm my answer for the orthocenter of a triangle?

Tags: analytic-geometry

I know how to find the orthocenter, but how do do I check to see if I have the right answer? For instance, once I find the centroid of a triangle I can use the centroid formula(a+b+c)/3 to check my answer. Is there anything like that for the orthocenter?

Answer (score 1):

If $|a|=|b|=|c|$, the orthocenter is given by $a+b+c$.

Comment: Is this the only way to check it? I assume you're talking about an equilateral triangle?

Comment: No, about a triangle which has the origin as its circumcenter.

Comment: Do you have a visual example?

Comment: For instance, consider $a=(0,1)$, $b=(1,0)$ and $c=(\frac35,\frac45)$ (all lying on the unit circle, so $|a|=|b|=|c|=1$. Its orthocenter is given by $a+b+c=(\frac85, \frac95)$.

Comment: Could you tell me how/why this works in the way that it  does? Thanks so much.

Comment: You can show that this works by checking that the line through $a$ and $a+b+c$ is perpendicular to the line through $b$ and $c$ (by using inner products). Alternatively, you can use that the centroid, circumcenter and orthocenter of any triangle are collinear (Euler's line), with the centroid dividing the segment joining the orthocenter and circumcenter in the ratio $1:2$.